# How to insert a numbered bullet list in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert a numbered bullet list when a user selects the button it will increment the counter

I have searched questions online and different types of loop condition statements

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton16_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton16.Click
    ToolStripButton16.CheckOnClick = False
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim numbList As String
    Dim buttonClickCount As Integer
    buttonClickCount = 0
    Do While (i = buttonClickCount)
        i += 1
        numbList = "            " & i & "." & vbCrLf
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(numbList)
    Loop
    buttonClickCount += 1
End Sub
```

Expected result:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
```

Comment: Have you checked all 84,500 hits when you google "numbered list in richtextbox"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but it should put you in the right direction.

```
'Using a class variable here allows you to keep an "application state".
Dim buttonClickCount as Integer = 0

Private Sub ToolStripButton16_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton16.Click

    ToolStripButton16.CheckOnClick = False

    buttonClickCount += 1
    Dim newValue As String = "            " & buttonClickCount  & "." & vbCrLf

    RichTextBox1.AppendText(newValue)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gerrit knew I was missing something but didn`t know where.

Comment: If my answer helped then please mark it as solved :)